# Why Won't Unity Let Me Use Animation For My Sprite?

Tags: user-interface, animation, sprite, unity-game-engine

I am making a countdown timer for my game and I need to animate the sprites: "3", "2", "1", "Go!". I know exactly how to do that animation so that is not my problem. My problem is: why won't Unity let me select all 4 sprites and animate them?
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

If you need more information or another picture, just let me know . Thank you! :)

Comment: you use Invoke for timers in Unity.

Comment: Are you trying to create a single animation that transitions between the 4 sub-images?

Comment: Hey guys I figured it out. This was my stupidity at its best. Thank you for your reply's though and I'll upvote your comments @JoeBlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't animate sprites, you animate a component (SpriteRenderer) using a Sprite. A sprite is a texture with some special attribute so it is considered specifically.

You don't animate a texture, it is just an image, you have a set of textures that you swap to create the effect of animation.

If you want to animate your 3-2-1-Go, you first need to create a Sprite gameObject, then assign a sprite texture to it, then create an Animator and an Animation clip.

Your animation would swap the current texture at specific time, most likely with Animation Event.

Actually, it might be easier to do it by script:

```
// Drag sprites, make sure they are in order (3->2->1->Go)
public Sprite[] sprites; 
public SpriteRenderer sp;
int index = 0;

void Start()
{
     // Check your sprites and sp
     InvokeRepeating("SwapSprite", 1.0f,1.0f); // Start timer to swap each second
     sp.sprite = sprites[index]; // Set initial sprite
}

private void SwapSprite()
{
     if(++index == sprites.Length) // Increase the index and check we run out of sprites
     { 
         CancelInvoke(); 
         sp.enabled = false; // Remove the counter 
         this.enabled = false; // That scripts is no more useful (could be destroyed)
         return; 
     }
     sp.sprite = sprites[index]; // Set new sprite
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out and my problem was that I was thinking completely wrong today! Instead of clicking on the Sprites to animate, I have to click on the UI Image. I spent hours trying to figure that out and was so easy after all!! UGHH! But thank you for your answer. I am going to mark it as correct since you took the time to respond and since you know what you're talking about. Thank you :)

Comment: And I will save that script in case of a future need for it! @Everts